# How to increase count and validate the user is liked or not using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, backend

I need to increase the like and dislike count in videoSchema, based upon the likedislikeSchema , please tell how to implement it.

For example, if user like the video, the like should be updated in videoSchema by count, and need to add the videoId and userId in likedislikeSchema. Based upon the likedislikeSchema , we need to verify the user that he is like or not.

My Like Dislike Model

```
const likedislikeSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    videoId: {
      type: ObjectId,
      ref: 'video',
    },
    userId: {
      type: ObjectId,
      ref: 'user',
    },
    like: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
    dislike: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
)

const LikedislikeModel = mongoose.model('Likedislike', likedislikeSchema)

module.exports = LikedislikeModel
```

and based upon it , I need to increase the count in Video schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const { ObjectId } = mongoose.Schema.Types

const videoSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    likes: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
    dislikes: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
)
const VideoModel = mongoose.model('Video', videoSchema)

module.exports = VideoModel
```

Answer (score 0):

How to do that depends on how strongly you want the reported number of likes/dislikes to be correct.

#### Loosely

If it is acceptable for the number of likes reported to be off by a few percent temporarily, i.e. will be corrected in a short period of time, you could do this update in multiple steps:

- Create on index in the likedislikes collection on:

```
{
  videoId: 1,
  userId: 1
}
```

- When processing a new like or dislike, use Model.findOneAndUpdate with both the [upsert and rawResult](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html#upsert) options
- If the user already has a like or dislike for that video, rawResult will cause the original document to be returned, so you can calculate the overall changes to the video's count
- findOneAndUpdate in the videos collection to apply the changes

Since the above processes the updates as separate steps it is possible for the first update to succeed but the second to fail.  If you don't handle every possible variation of that in your code, it is possible for the counts in the video document to be out of sync with the likedisklies collection.
To remedy that, periodically iterate the videos, and run an aggregation to tally the count of likes and dislikes, and update the video document.

This will give you reasonably accurate counts normally, with precise counts when the periodic count is run.

#### Strongly

If for some reason you cannot tolerate any imprecision in the counts, you should use [multi-document transactions](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/transactions/) to ensure that both updates either succeed or fail together.

Note that with transactions there will be some document-locking, so individual updates may take a bit longer than the loose option.